# Can you extract the base of the logarithm used in a Matplotlib logarithimic axis?

Tags: matplotlib, logarithm

If someone had a created Matplotlib figure with, e.g.,

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xscale('log', basex=np.e)
```

Is there a way to extract from the axis what that `basex` value was? I can get the `xscale` with `ax.get_xscale()`, but there's no equivalent `ax.get_basex()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `get_scale` return the `name` field of the actual used `matplotlib.scale.LogScale` object `ax.get_xaxis()._scale` instead of the object itself, I unfortunately did not find another way then accessing `base` of the private field `_scale` directly. Accessing private fields is discouraged, but

```
ax.get_xaxis()._scale.base
```

gets you the result.